# SQL Server updates are sequential or parallel?

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure which has only two update statements. Both are on same table updating data based on different columns. For example

```
update table1 
set column1 = somevalue, column2 = somevalue 
where column3 = somevalue

update table1 
set column3 = somevalue, column2 = somevalue 
where column1 = somevalue
```

Intermittently I am getting an error

> Transaction (Process ID "different number)) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

Process id is pointing to the same stored procedure when I check in SQL Server using command `sp_who`.

There can be a situation where both update statements can update same row. can this be a reason of deadlock?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_tib_details
    (@tib_id INT, @sys_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tib_sys_asc
    SET tib_id = @tib_id
    WHERE sys_id = @sys_id

    UPDATE tib_sys_asc           
    SET sys_id = @sys_id
    WHERE tib_id = @tib_id
END
```

Comment: Sharing the code of your procedure would help considerably here.

Comment: added code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't happen if the updates execute in the same process. A single process can't cause a deadlock with itself.

If this update is being trigged by some other process, and isn't somehow protected from concurrency, you could experience a deadlock.

Deadlock occurs when two processes are each mid-transaction and waiting on the other to complete before they can continue. In this case, for example

```
Process A starts, and updates row 1
Process B starts, and updates row 2
Process A now wants to update row 2, and must wait for Process B to commit
Process B now wants to update row 1, and must wait for Process A to commit
```

The database engine is pretty good at detecting these cross dependencies, and chooses which process to kill. If `Process B` is killed, `Process A` can finally update row 2 and commit, or vice versa.

In your case you should decide what the appropriate end result should be. If you don't care in which order operations complete (last in wins) then just commit after each update. If you do care, then you should be able to write an exclusive lock around the entire operation (i.e. `Process B` waits until the entirety of `Process A` has completed).

Comment: Thanks. I am not using transactions in my procedure. There must be some other jobs running trying to update same table at same time. What is the best way to find the other process or to handle this.

Comment: Actually your procedure is using transactions, they are just implicit. Every single DDL statement ALWAYS utilizes a transaction. This is due to the atomic and durability aspects of the ACID principle.